# How to Load Only Five Cell When Table View Scrolled?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I make a tableview With JSON Data it Contain Pagination and Each Webservices Page Contain 10 Data but I want when Table view Scroll then i want load Only 5items in Each time how it possible? please Give me Solution.

My Code For That

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
NSInteger currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
NSInteger maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height- scrollView.frame.size.height;
if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 0)
{
pageNum = pageNum + 1;
[self getData];
}
}
-(void)getData
{
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/news.php?page=%d",pageNum]];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}
```

And FetchData Method Is

```
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata
 {
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
self.newsTable.tableFooterView = spinner;
if (responsedata.length > 0)
{
    [spinner startAnimating];
    NSError* error;
    self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if ([[_json objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[_json objectForKey:@"data"];
        [self.imageArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
        [self.newsTable reloadData];
        NSLog(@"images,%@",self.imageArray);
    }
}
[self.spinner stopAnimating];
self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped=YES;
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

return self.imageArray.count;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (self.imageArray == nil || self.imageArray.count < 1)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    return 1;
}
[self.newsTable reloadData];
}
```

I Know it is asked Many times But i not Get Answer.Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    NSInteger currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    NSInteger maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height- scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 0)
    {
        if([self.mTenarray count]==0) {
            pageNum = pageNum + 1;
            [self getData];
        } else {
            [self.imageArray addObjectsFromArray:self.mTenarray];
            [self.mTenarray removeAllObjects];
            [self.newsTable reloadData];
        }
    }
}
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    self.newsTable.tableFooterView = spinner;
    if (responsedata.length > 0)
    {
        [spinner startAnimating];
        NSError* error;
        self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        if ([[_json objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[_json objectForKey:@"data"];
            [self.mTenarray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
            NSArray *mfivedatarray = [self.mTenarray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)];
            [self.imageArray addObjectsFromArray:mfivedatarray];
            self.mTenarray  // remove first five objects
            [self.newsTable reloadData];
            NSLog(@"images,%@",self.imageArray);
        }
    }
    [self.spinner stopAnimating];
    self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped=YES;
}
```

Comment: What Work of this Line self.mTenarray  // remove first five objects?  And not Understand mTenArry is what?

Comment: you write the logic to remove remove the first five object from this array.Declare the tenarray globally which contains the data came from server

Comment: Not Solved Here When I scrolled First Five Data Was Remove and Second Five Take Place I want keep both Data.

Comment: Do you used exactly what I posted.And in the above logic I am not removing any data from the imageArray.

Comment: i write your Code then Nothing will be Fetched From WebServices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63923/discussion-between-ramesh-muthe-and-ashish-gabani).

Comment: I try it but it Display First Page 5 Data and Then Direct Second Page 5 Data First page Remaining data was not display on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The way we did it on our server is we gave the API an extra "**page size**" parameter so that when you request data like:

```
http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/news.php?page=3&pageSize=5
```

It returns only 5 results instead of the default amount, which is 10 in your case. This means we don't have to do any fancy filtering on the iOS side of things.

Comment: But When Page Was Increase then I mean When page Was increased and Conatin 4 to 5 page then?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. When page increase to page 4, page 5, you still request 5 results from those pages. If a set of 100 results by default returns 20 results per page, then that's 5 pages but if you only return 5 results per page, then you'll have 20 pages instead of 5. Is that what you want to ask?

Comment: You say that set page=3&pageSize=5 but when my Webservice data increment in future then pageNumber is increment then what is solution?

Comment: It doesn't matter if pageNumber increment. That's the point of pagination, you keep scrolling until you don't have a "next" page link in your JSON returned results. Usually with REST service, you have a previous and next page key-value pair that identifies the next page's URL, you check if next page == nil then you know you don't have anymore results to show so you stop trying to get next page.